# IPS Connect not logging in via cookie

Tags: php, phpfox, ipb

So I have setup my IPB install as a slave and a PHPFox install as my master.
When I login to PHPFox all the info that I will use are put into cookies as it is suppoed to be. When I go to my forum I can still see the cookies with all the info but I'm not logged in... Why is this?

Both PHPFox and IPB use md5 hash and salt. The only difference is that the salt in IPB is 5 long and PHPFox 3. But I don't think that have anythin to say since it's hashed again in the IPS connect

This is the code I put in my template file:

```
{if Phpfox::isUser() && !Phpfox::getUserBy('profile_page_id')}
<?php
                    setcookie( 'ipscm_user', Phpfox::getUserBy('user_name'), time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
                    setcookie( 'ipscm_pass',  Phpfox::getLib('hash')->setHash('password'), time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
                    setcookie( 'ipsconnect_' . md5( $url . 'ipsconnect.php' ), '1', time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
?>
{/if}
```

This is my IPSConnect.php file. Is there any way to turn off debug mode so I can see if there is any errors?
The include.php file connects to the database and check if user matches table. When I print in that include file all the information is right.

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * @class   ipsConnect
 * @brief   This is where you put the code for your application
 *
 */
class ipsConnect
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Use this to do any initiation required by your application
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->secret_key = '----';

        require_once 'include.php';
        $this->url = 'http://www.simgoodies.com/com';
        $this->url_to_this_file = $this->url . '/ipsconnect.php';

        $this->db = $db;
    }
    /**
     * Process Login
     *
     * @param   string  Identifier - may be 'id', 'email' or 'username'
     * @param   string  Value for identifier (for example, the user's ID number)
     * @param   string  The password, md5 encoded
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key (see login method) . Identifier Value )
     * @param   string  Redirect URL, Base64 encoded
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key . $redirect )
     * @return  mixed   If the redirect URL is provided, this function should redirect the user to that URL with three additional paramaters:
     *                      connect_status      value from below
     *                      connect_id          the ID number in this app
     *                      connect_username    the username
     *                      connect_displayname the display name
     *                      connect_email       the email address
     *                      connect_unlock      If the account is locked, the number of seconds until it unlocks
     *                  If blank, will output to screen a JSON object with the same parameters
     *                  Values:
     *                      SUCCESS         login successful
     *                      WRONG_AUTH      Password incorrect
     *                      NO_USER         Identifier did not match member account
     *                      MISSING_DATA    Identifier or password was blank
     *                      ACCOUNT_LOCKED  Account has been locked by brute-force prevention
     *                      VALIDATING      Account has not been validated
     */
    public function login( $identifier, $identifierValue, $md5Password, $key, $redirect, $redirectHash )
    {
        if ( $redirect )
        {
            $redirect = ( ( $key == md5( $this->masterKey . $identifierValue ) ) and ( $redirectHash == md5( $this->masterKey . $redirect ) ) ) ? $redirect : base64_encode( $this->url );
        }

        if ( !$identifier or !$identifierValue or !$md5Password )
        {
            $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'connect_status' => 'MISSING_DATA' ) );
        }

        switch ( $identifier )
        {
            case 'id':
                $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_id=" . intval( $identifierValue ) )->fetch_array();
                break;

            case 'username':
                $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $identifierValue ) ."'" )->fetch_array();
                break;

            case 'email':
                $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE email='". $this->db->escape_string( $identifierValue ) ."'" )->fetch_array();
                break;
        }

        echo "Tester";
        echo $user['user_name'];

        if ( isset( $user['user_id'] ) )
        {
            if ( $md5Password == $user['password'] )
            {
                if ( $redirect )
                {
                    setcookie( 'ipscm_user', $user['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
                    setcookie( 'ipscm_pass', $user['password'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
                    setcookie( 'ipsconnect_' . md5( $this->url_to_this_file ), '1', time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
                }

                $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'connect_status' => 'SUCCESS', 'connect_id' => $user['user_id'], 'connect_username' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_displayname' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_email' => $user['email'], 'connect_unlock' => 0 ) );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'connect_status' => 'WRONG_AUTH', 'connect_id' => $user['user_id'], 'connect_username' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_displayname' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_email' => $user['email'], 'connect_unlock' => 0 ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'connect_status' => 'NO_USER' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process Logout
     *
     * @param   int     ID number
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key (see login method) . ID number )
     * @param   string  Redirect URL, Base64 encoded
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key . $redirect )
     * @return  mixed   If the redirect URL is provided, this function should redirect the user to that URL
     *                  If blank, will output blank screen
     */
    public function logout( $id, $key, $redirect, $redirectHash )
    {
        // Check key
        if ( $key != md5( $this->secret_key . $id ) )
        {
            $this->_return( base64_encode( $this->url ) );
        }

        setcookie( 'ipscm_user', '', -1, '/' );
        setcookie( 'ipscm_pass', '', -1, '/' );
        setcookie( 'ipsconnect_' . md5( $this->url_to_this_file ), '0', time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );

        // Return
        if ( $redirect )
        {
            $redirect = ( $redirectHash == md5( $this->masterKey . $redirect ) ) ? $redirect : base64_encode( $this->url );     
        }
        $this->_return( $redirect );
    }

    /**
     * Register a new account
     *
     * @param   string  Key - this can be anything which is known only to the applications. Never reveal this key publically.
     *                  For IPS Community Suite installs, this key can be obtained in the Login Management page in the ACP
     * @param   string  Username
     * @param   string  Display name
     * @param   string  The password, md5 encoded
     * @param   string  Email address
     * @param   string  If set, this account should be considered to be waiting for email validation. If this is the case, a URL is provided which will be the URL from which the user to resend the email.
     * @return  void    Outputs to screen JSON object with 2 parameters 
                        'status'    One of the following values:
                                        BAD_KEY             The key provided was invalid
                                        SUCCESS             Account created
                                        EMAIL_IN_USE        Email is already in use
                                        USERNAME_IN_USE     Username is already in use
                                        BAD_KEY             Key was invalid
                                        MISSING_DATA        Not all data was provided
                                        FAIL                Other error
                        'id' with master ID number (0 if fail) - if user already exists, will provide ID of existing user
     */
    public function register( $key, $username, $displayname, $md5Password, $email, $revalidateurl )
    {
        // Check key
        if ( $key != $this->secret_key )
        {
            echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'BAD_KEY', 'user_id' => 0 ) );
            exit;
        }

        if ( !$email or !$md5Password )
        {
            echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'MISSING_DATA', 'user_id' => 0 ) );
            exit;
        }

        // Create the account
        $this->db->query( "INSERT INTO phpfox_user ( user_name, email, password ) VALUES ( '". $this->db->escape_string( $username ) ."', '". $this->db->escape_string( $email ) ."', '". $this->db->escape_string( $md5Password ) ."' )" );

        // Return
        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'FAIL', 'user_id' => 0 ) );
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Validate Cookie Data
     *
     * @param   string  JSON encoded cookie data
     * @return  void    Outputs to screen a JSON object with the bollowing properties:
     *                      connect_status      SUCCESS, VALIDATING (successful, but account has not been validated) or FAIL
     *                      connect_id          the ID number in this app
     *                      connect_username    the username
     *                      connect_displayname the display name
     *                      connect_email       the email address
     */
    public function cookies( $data )
    {
        $cookies = json_decode( stripslashes( urldecode( $data ) ), TRUE );

        if ( isset( $cookies['ipscm_user'] ) )
        {   
            if ( $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $cookies['ipscm_user'] ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                if ( $user['password'] == $cookies['ipscm_pass'] )
                {
                    echo json_encode( array( 'connect_status' => 'SUCCESS', 'connect_id' => $user['user_id'], 'connect_username' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_displayname' => $user['user_name'], 'connect_email' => $user['email'] ) );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }

        echo json_encode( array( 'connect_status' => 'FAIL' ) );
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Check data
     *
     * @param   string  Key - this can be anything which is known only to the applications. Never reveal this key publically.
     *                  For IPS Community Suite installs, this key can be obtained in the Login Management page in the ACP
     * @param   int     If provided, do not throw an error if the "existing user" is the user with this ID
     * @param   string  Username
     * @param   string  Display Name
     * @param   string  Email address
     * @return  void    Outputs to screen a JSON object with four properties (status, username, displayname, email) - 'status' will say "SUCCESS" - the remainding 3 properties will each contain a boolean value, or NULL if no value was provided.
     *                  The boolean value indicates if it is OK to register a new account with that data (this may be because there is no existing user with that, or the app allows duplicates of that data)
     *                  If the key is incorrect - 'status' will be "BAD_KEY" and the remaining 3 parameters will all be NULL.
     */
    public function check( $key, $id, $username, $displayname, $email )
    {
        $return = array( 'user_name' => NULL, 'user_name' => NULL, 'email' => NULL );

        // Check key
        if ( $key != $this->secret_key )
        {
            echo json_encode( array_merge( array( 'status' => 'BAD_KEY' ), $return ) );
            exit;
        }

        // Check username
        if ( $username )
        {
            if ( $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $username ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                $return['user_name'] = FALSE; 
            }
            else
            {
                $return['user_name'] = TRUE;
            }
        }

        // Check displayname
        if ( $displayname )
        {
            if ( $username == $displayname )
            {
                $return['displayname'] = $return['username'];
            }
            else
            {
                if ( $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $displayname ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
                {
                    $return['displayname'] = FALSE; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $return['displayname'] = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check Email
        if ( $email )
        {
            if ( $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE email='". $this->db->escape_string( $email ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                $return['email'] = FALSE; 
            }
            else
            {
                $return['email'] = TRUE;
            }
        }

        // Return
        echo json_encode( array_merge( array( 'status' => 'SUCCESS' ), $return ) );
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Change account data
     *
     * @param   int     ID number
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key (see login method) . ID number )
     * @param   string  New username (blank means do not change)
     * @param   string  New displayname (blank means do not change)
     * @param   string  New email address (blank means do not change)
     * @param   string  New password, md5 encoded (blank means do not change)
     * @param   string  Redirect URL, Base64 encoded
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key . $redirect )
     * @return  mixed   If the redirect URL is provided, this function should redirect the user to that URL with a single paramater - 'status'
     *                  If blank, will output to screen a JSON object with the same parameter
     *                  Values:
     *                      BAD_KEY             Invalid Key
     *                      NO_USER             ID number not match any member account
     *                      SUCCESS             Information changed successfully
     *                      USERNAME_IN_USE     The chosen username was in use and as a result NO information was changed
     *                      DISPLAYNAME_IN_USE  The chosen username was in use and as a result NO information was changed
     *                      EMAIL_IN_USE        The chosen username was in use and as a result NO information was changed
     *                      MISSING_DATA        No details to be changed were provided
     */
    public function change( $id, $key, $username, $displayname, $email, $md5Password, $redirect, $redirectHash )
    {
        if ( $key != md5( $this->secret_key . $id ) )
        {
            $this->_return( base64_encode( $this->url ), array( 'status' => 'BAD_KEY' ) );
        }

        if ( $redirect )
        {
            $redirect = ( $redirectHash == md5( $this->masterKey . $redirect ) ) ? $redirect : base64_encode( $this->url );
        }

        $user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $_COOKIE['ipscm_user'] ) ."'" )->fetch_array();
        if ( !isset( $user['user_id'] ) )
        {
            $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'NO_USER' ) );
        }

        $update = array();

        if ( $username and $username != $user['user_name'] )
        {
            if ( $_user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $username ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'USERNAME_IN_USE' ) );
            }

            $update['user_name'] = $this->db->escape_string( $username );
        }

        if ( !$username and $displayname and $displayname != $user['user_name'] )
        {
            if ( $_user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE user_name='". $this->db->escape_string( $displayname ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'DISPLAYNAME_IN_USE' ) );
            }

            $update['user_name'] = $this->db->escape_string( $displayname );
        }

        if ( $email and $email != $user['email'] )
        {
            if ( $_user = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM phpfox_user WHERE email='". $this->db->escape_string( $email ) ."'" )->fetch_array() )
            {
                $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'DISPLAYNAME_IN_USE' ) );
            }

            $update['email'] = $this->db->escape_string( $email );
        }

        if ( $md5Password )
        {
            $update['password'] = md5( $md5Password );
        }

        if ( empty( $update ) )
        {
            $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'MISSING_DATA' ) );
        }

        $update['user_name'] = isset( $update['user_name'] ) ? $update['user_name'] : $user['user_name'];
        $update['email'] = isset( $update['email'] ) ? $update['email'] : $user['email'];
        $update['password'] = isset( $update['password'] ) ? $update['password'] : $user['password'];
        $this->db->query( "UPDATE phpfox_user SET user_name='{$update['username']}', email='{$update['email']}', password='{$update['password']}' WHERE user_id={$user['user_id']};" );

        if ( $redirect )
        {
            setcookie( 'ipscm_pass', $update['password'], time()+60*60*24*30, '/' );
        }
        $success = TRUE;

        $this->_return( $redirect, array( 'status' => 'SUCCESS' ) );

    }

    /**
     * Account is validated
     *
     * @param   int     ID number
     * @param   string  md5( IPS Connect Key (see login method) . ID number )
     */
    public function validate( $id, $key )
    {
        if ( $key != md5( $this->secret_key . $id ) )
        {
            echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'BAD_KEY' ) );
        }

        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'SUCCESS' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Delete account(s)
     *
     * @param   array   ID Numbers
     * @param   string  md5(  IPS Connect Key (see login method) . json_encode( ID number ) )
     */
    public function delete( $ids, $key )
    {
        if ( $key != md5( $this->secret_key . json_encode( $ids ) ) )
        {
            echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'BAD_KEY' ) );
        }

        foreach ( json_decode( $ids, TRUE ) as $id )
        {
            $id = intval( $id );
            $this->db->query( "DELETE FROM phpfox_user WHERE id={$id};" );
        }

        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'SUCCESS' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Handle redirect / output
     *
     * @param   string  Redirect URL, Base64 encoded
     * @param   array   Params
     * @return  null    Outputs to screen or redirects
     */
    protected function _return( $redirect, $params=array() )
    {
        if ( $redirect )
        {
            header( 'Location: ' . base64_decode( $redirect ) . ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['noparams'] ) and $_REQUEST['noparams'] ) ? '' : ( '&' . http_build_query( $params ) ) ) );
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !empty( $params ) )
            {
                echo json_encode( $params );
            }
            exit;
        }
    }   
}

/**
 *
 * Map - can modify to add additional parameters, but the IPS Community Suite will only send the defaults
 *
 */
$map = array(
    'login'     => array( 'idType', 'id', 'password', 'key', 'redirect', 'redirectHash' ),
    'logout'    => array( 'id', 'key', 'redirect', 'redirectHash' ),
    'register'  => array( 'key', 'username', 'displayname', 'password', 'email', 'revalidateurl' ),
    'cookies'   => array( 'data' ),
    'check'     => array( 'key', 'id', 'username', 'displayname', 'email' ),
    'change'    => array( 'id', 'key', 'username', 'displayname', 'email', 'password', 'redirect', 'redirectHash' ),
    'validate'  => array( 'id', 'key' ),
    'delete'    => array( 'id', 'key' )
    );

/**
 *
 * Process Logic - do not modify
 *
 */ 
$ipsConnect = new ipsConnect();
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['act'] ) and isset( $map[ $_REQUEST['act'] ] ) )
{
    $params = array();
    foreach ( $map[ $_REQUEST['act'] ] as $k )
    {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ $k ] ) )
        {
            $params[ $k ] = $_REQUEST[ $k ];
        }
        else
        {
            $params[ $k ] = '';
        }
    }

    call_user_func_array( array( $ipsConnect, $_REQUEST['act'] ), $params );
}

exit;
```

Comment: Adding php code to a template file is an awful way around it. Learn how phpfox works: make a plugin, use a hook in the user module, auth service. And dont post entire code here, use a pastebin

Comment: @Purefan Ok, I will try to make a hook/plugin. But will that help in any way? Since the cookies are set anyway.

I didn't know what part of the code to post since all of it is relevant.